# laravel - Allowed memory size exhausted in queue

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I want to fire import from Excel file by queues so I do:
**queue file**

```
/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    Excel::filter('chunk')->load(storage_path('engine-valves.xlsx'))->chunk(500, function($results) {
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::put(storage_path('data2.txt'), json_encode($results));
    });
}
```

but on listen process I getting standard error `Allowed memory size of xxx bytes exhausted`. For one moment I tried to set `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` but still I getting this error. There is full line with this error:
`PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 100663304 bytes) in [app_path]\vendor\phpoffice\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 889`.
I'm using: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel
Where is can be problem?

Comment: Too big file to keep in memory so you would need to read it as a ByteStream or something

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is not a good practice but you can set the memory limit just for the method

```
/**
* Execute the job.
*
* @return void
*/
public function handle()
{
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    Excel::filter('chunk')->load(storage_path('engine-valves.xlsx'))>chunk(500, function($results) {
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::put(storage_path('data2.txt'), json_encode($results));
    });
}
```

with memory limit = -1, you dont have limit.

Comment: Like I wrote in question - I have setted this for test and I still getting this error, please read it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should change maximum upload file size in your php.ini file.  So, open your php.ini file and find ***upload_max_filesize***. Then change the value. You should also change ***post_max_size*** directive in php.ini file.

Comment: Do you have an example of what that would look like? It's usually best to expand upon suggestions.

Comment: changed as you suggested. Thanks.